# Display data from single column in multiple columns in GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying data from my table (one column) in a grid, but the data is large (about 50 entries). Can I display the data in multiple columns/ rows so that it is easy for the user to read without scrolling down?
 Here's my code.

ASPX:

```
   <asp:GridView AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Wheat" 
                 ID="GDV_1" runat="server"  
                 EnableModelValidation="true" 
                 AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="GDV_1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                 AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" DataKeyNames="SROID">

       <Columns>
           <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="SRONameinEnglish" 
                               HeaderText="SRO Name" 
                               DataNavigateUrlFields="SROID" 
                               DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Webredirect2.aspx?SROID={0}" />

       </Columns>

   </asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
 protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FeesBLL p = new FeesBLL();
            GDV_1.DataSource = p.table(txt_1.Text);

            //GDV_1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            GDV_1.DataBind();
}
```

Kindly give you suggestion fr achieving the required result.

Comment: use datalist instead of gridview for this purpose.make Repeatcolumn property to 2 or 3 as you want in datalist.

Comment: Use gridview pagination